# restify: why serving working directory is not possible?

Tags: node.js, static, restify

I have a restify server with node.js I use to make some development and tests and to do so, I use serveStatic.

I wonder why I cannot use the following configuration without getting 403 errors:

```
server.get(/.*/, restify.serveStatic({
  directory: '.',
  default: "index.html"
}));
```

Although if I make a link to my current dir:

```
ln -s . serverDir
```

This will work:

```
server.get(/.*/, restify.serveStatic({
  directory: './serverDir',
  default: "index.html"
}));
```

What is the reason for this ? Security ? Bug ? Software or network limitation ?

Is there something I should know or read about serving static files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you user __dirname instead of '.' to indicate the current directory?

```
server.get(/.*/, restify.serveStatic({
  directory: __dirname,
  default: "index.html"
}));
```

Comment: '.' is not the recommended way to provide the current directory. I guess restify is not resolving the path properly.

Comment: I also tried "./" and it did not work. So it's strange to me that "./serverDir" works

Comment: Problem is @https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify/blob/master/lib/plugins/static.js#L102, the opts.directory is not resolved, only normalized hence the error.