# restify js default root page

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I'm trying to write restful application using node.js restify. Here is my application's code :

```
var restify = require('restify');

var server = restify.createServer();

server.get(/.*/, restify.serveStatic({
    directory: 'content',
    default: 'index.html'
 }));

server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

So, I can access index.html only by `http://localhost:3000/index.html`.
I also expect to see my index.html page on the root url, `http://localhost:3000/` but now i'm receiving there

```
{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"/"}
```

Comment: should `server.get(/.*/` not be `server.get(/*` or similar ? what's the dot for ?

Comment: It is regexp that is maching any string. Dot means any symbol, star means that it may be any number of symbols.

Comment: Ah, nice feature -- does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399648/restify-why-serving-working-directory-is-not-possible ? - regarding the `directory` -  - only other thing I can think of

Comment: I have tried that - didn't help with my issue.

Comment: I was able to get your example working - are you sure you have a 'content' directory with a 'index.html' file in it? Good to verify the basics :)

Comment: Yes, I am, I can even reach it, but as http://localhost:3000/index.html, not as http://localhost:3000/.
Did you get index.html on http://localhost:3000/ url?

Answer (score 4):

Give this a try:

```
server.get(/\//, restify.serveStatic({
    directory: './content',
    default: 'index.html'
 }));
```